# itertools.product() of multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

My df looks like

```
a  b   c   
0  1   nan  
0  2   3   
0  3   4 
1  1   nan
```

I need a itertools.product() like combination of the entries in rows within groups of 'a'. Here 2 possible ways, since the second row has 2 different values:

```
   a  b   
1  0  1    
   0  2   
   0  3 
2  0  1
   0  3
   0  3 
3  0  1    
   0  2   
   0  4 
4  0  1
   0  3
   0  4 
5  1  1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
df=pd.concat([y.dropna(axis=1,thresh=1).ffill(1).melt('a') for x , y in df.groupby('a')])
     a variable  value
0  0.0        b    1.0
1  0.0        b    2.0
2  0.0        b    3.0
3  0.0        c    1.0
4  0.0        c    3.0
5  0.0        c    3.0
0  1.0        b    1.0
```

Comment: @MirekG what kind of index ？

Comment: I noticed a small problem: if in this case, column 1 or 3 would have had more than 1 filled cell, it would not have worked. I need a product of all cells. In this case it's 1*2*1=2 possibilities, for 2*2*3 it would have been 12 for example.

Comment: @MirekG I suggest do not edited your question like this . this is 2nd time you edited your original question

Comment: do you have an idea how to melt() with all different combinations?